# How to update my selected options in the multiselect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a select which shows a series of data that I retrieve from an api.
When initializing it it shows the already selected tabs, which is fine. The problem is that when trying to select more options or delete the ones that are, nothing happens.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Externals
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import validate from 'validate.js';
import _ from 'underscore';

// Material helpers
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

import moment from 'moment';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import Select from 'react-select';

// Material components
import {
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';

// Shared utilities
import validators from 'common/validators';
// Shared components
import {
  Portlet,
  PortletContent,
  PortletFooter
} from 'components';

// Component styles
import styles from './styles';

// Form validation schema
import schema from './schema';


class UserDetails extends Component {


  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      offices: [],
      officesSelected: [],

      isValid: false,
      isLoading: false,
      submitError: null
  };

    fetch(global.url_base+'/office' , {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        id_user: this.props.location.id_user
      }),
      headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      let langString = responseJson;
      let officesSelected = langString.map(item => ({ value: item.id_office, label: item.name_office, image: item.logo_office }));
      this.setState({
        officesSelected
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }

  componentWillMount() {
      let currentComponent = this;

      url = global.url_base+'/office'  
      fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        let langString = responseJson;

        let offices = langString.map(item => ({ value: item.id_office, label: item.name_office }));

        currentComponent.setState({
          offices
        });
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  handleChangeMultiple = (event) => {

    const value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = event.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        value.push(event[i].value);
    }
    const newState = { ...this.state };
    var field = 'id_office';
    newState.submitError = null;
    newState.touched[field] = true;
    newState.values[field] = value;
    this.setState(newState, this.validateForm);

  }

  render() {

    const { classes, className, ...rest } = this.props;
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      isValid,
      submitError,
      offices,
      officesSelected
    } = this.state;

    const rootClassName = classNames(classes.root, className);

    return (

        <Select 
            className={classes.textField}
            styles={selectStyles}
            label="Office"
            name="id_office"
            onChange={this.handleChangeMultiple}
            options={offices}
            value={officesSelected}
            isMulti 
        />
```

If I remove the function "value={officesSelected}" I can change and add tabs of the multi select without problems, but I can't recover the already selected tabs data from the api. It always shows as if I don't have any tab selected.

Comment: Hi Vortex, it seems you are using react-select and not material-ui select as implied from the question tag. Also, the code you provided is not enough. I can't see when officesSelected value change. Please provide more code, preferably a working example on Codesandbox

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Here I edited my code as concise as possible, I removed several unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is this line:

```
value={officesSelected}
```

*officesSelected* only changes in your constructor. 
Your constructor will be called only once, before the component mounts (and as long as it's still mounted). 
That means, your select value will be determined in the constructor and won't change during the component lifecycle. 
To achieve what you want, you need to set the state of *officesSelected* in *handleChangeMultiple*. 
Something like:

```
handleChangeMultiple = (event) => {

    const value = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = event.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        value.push(event[i].value);
    }
    const newState = { ...this.state };
    var field = 'id_office';
    newState.submitError = null;
    newState.touched[field] = true;
    newState.values[field] = value;
    newState.officesSelected = event; // I only added this line
    this.setState(newState, this.validateForm);

}
```

That should give you the ability to select more options and delete the already selected ones.

---

Just as a side note - making api calls in the constructor is not best practice.

You should make api calls in *ComponentDidMount*: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Thank you very much! it works! the truth I'm new at React, it's my first application, I also appreciate the advice.